# How to use GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl function in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `win32security` module. More precisely, I need to use `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl()`([PyACL Object](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyACL.html)). How can I get the `PyTRUSTEE trustee` that needs to call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some result using @eryksun help:

```
def print_permissions(mask, username):
print("Effective permissions for: ", username, "\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000001), "\tReadData\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000002), "\tWriteData\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000004), "\tAppendData\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000008), "\tReadEa\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000010), "\tWriteEa\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000020), "\tExecute\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000040), "\tDeleteChildn\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000080), "\tReadAttributes\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00000100), "\tWriteAttributes\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00010000), "\tDelete\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00020000), "\tReadControl\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00040000), "\tWriteDac\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00080000), "\tWriteOwner\n",
      bool(mask & 0x00100000), "\tSynchronize\n")

dacl = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(
FILENAME,
win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION).GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
mask = dacl.GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(
{'TrusteeForm': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, 'TrusteeType': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
 'Identifier': username})

print_permissions(mask, username)
```